# JMeter Script to extract an id from Json response

Tags: jmeter

I need to extract id which as Status 1. How can I achieve it.
Example: id (abc) in below example as its status is 1
''''

```
{
    "Documents": [
        {
            "id": "abc",
            "Status": 1,
        }, 
        {
            "id": "pgr",
            "Status": 2,
        }, 
        {
            "id": "abc",
            "Status": 2,
        }
    ]
}
```

''''
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor), the relevant [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query would be something like:

```
$..[?(@.Status == 1)].id
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JSONPath Filter Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)